# VLAN Implementation

Tags: networking, vlan

I'm trying to separate a wireless guest network from an internal network.

I made a little drawing of what I did to separate it:

[image: Link to drawing]

Before, there existed no VLANs so this is what I'm trying to introduce.

Right now the whole .2.x network (no/default VLAN, green) is working. I just can't get the mobile clients to connect to any further than the distant end of the access point (named "WLAN Router" in the drawing).

So ping from a wireless client to the access point is fine (.1.5), ping to the distant side of the access point is fine (.2.2) but I can't reach the Cisco switch (.2.106). All devices use .2.1 (internet router) as a gateway, subnet masks are /24.

From what I understand all access ports should be untagged (here, there is only one which is not on the default VLAN) and the trunk between the switches should be tagged, no? (BTW: VLANS 1 & 5 both go over the trunk)

What am I missing here?

I hope I provided enough explanation.

Comment: What is your "WAN Router"?

Comment: Please identify what you consider the 'public' / guest wireless network - is it the `.1.x` network? And are you trying to prevent `.1.122` from having access to the `.2.x` hosts?

Comment: "WAN router" meaning last device before the internet? If so: `.2.1`
And yes, public/guest is the `.1.x` network which should be prevented from accessing the `.2.x` network

Comment: I meant WLAN, apologies...

Comment: The WLAN Router is a LinkSys... WRT something. Sorry, I'm not on site right now. 
The switches involved are only Layer 2 switches I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, you have a nasty situation.

- Think of VLANs as separate cables. Currently there is no path for the data between the `.2.2` interface of the WLAN router, and the rest of the `.2.x` network. All of these hosts should be on the same network/VLAN.
- If you were to connect them to the same VLAN, then all of the guest / public / **untrusted** Wifi clients would be able to access your "internal" network - not good.

---

I would recommend that you rearrange your network, as shown in the diagram below.

Don't forget that in the consumer space a "Router" typically refers to the following network components in a single box:

- Modem (possibly... if you're on DSL, then likely, otherwise you'll probably have a separate cable modem)
- NAT-ing Router
- DHCP Server & DNS Relay
- Switch
- Wifi Access Point

[image: Network Architecture]

Split the network into "*Trusted*" and "*Untrusted*" zones, and as you get deeper, the trust levels go up (the reverse of what you've proposed).

You might need to get couple of extra bits of hardware to accomplish this.
The router on the border of *Trusted* / *Untrusted* could be what is often referred to as a "Cable Router" in the consumer space. This means that it has an Ethernet / RJ45 WAN port, not a DSL port.

Using one of these would probably give you the behaviour that you're after - Internal Hosts would not be accessible from your Guest Wifi (without setting up port forwarding / NAT), but the internal hosts can still access the internet, and potentially the Guest Wifi hosts.

---

NOTE: this architecture also negates the need for VLANs, unless you need to run multiple guest Wireless Access Points through your site.

Comment: We were trying to pull it off without having to buy anything but it seems there is no way around it. Thank you very much for your assistance!

Comment: Hey, I have one more question. I understand the bottom cisco switch has two ways to get to the `.2.x` network, which is a no no. 
But what if I just make the lower red leg a transfer network and call it `.3.x` for example? Wouldn't that help?

Comment: But how would that route to the internet? You'll have a `.3.x` network that consists of a single "wire" - same problem.

Comment: Oh yeah right. There also would be no routing between `.2.x` and `.3.x`
OK, guess we really have to buy something here. Thanks again!